# Python - List sorting & Asymptotic Complexity

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, complexity-theory

I have a list `arr` and a value `dif`. I need to create an algorithm that will go through the values in `arr`, subtract them (the largest value after subtraction can be maximally `dif`) and then output the resulting values in new lists.

I created this code. The first problem is that it is broken if there are 3+ lists in the output. The second problem is the time complexity - if I'm not mistaken, it is `O(n^2)` so it's really slow.

I've tried to create this using *Insertion sort* and *Binary search*, but I never get the right result. The output was even worse than in the above code.

Can someone help me? How to simplify the algorithm and how to make it work correctly?

#### Code :

```py
arr = [9, 3, 11, 5, 10, 4]
arr2 = [16, 13, 3, 1, 8, 2]
dif = 3


def func(arr):
    pre_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        result = []

        for j in range(0, len(arr)):
                sub = arr[i] - arr[j]

                if (abs(sub) <= dif):
                    result.append(arr[j])

        if (result not in pre_list):
            pre_list.append(result)
            print(result)

func(arr)
```

#### Output:

arr:

```
[9, 11, 10]
[3, 5, 4]
```

arr 1:

```
[16, 13]
[3, 1, 2]
[8]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "go through the values in arr, subtract them (the largest value after subtraction can be maximally dif)"?  Given arr= [9, 11, 10] and diff = 3, what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: What I meant was that there cannot be an element in the resulting list that is >3 after subtracting each element from that list. For example - `|9-11| =2`, `|9-10|=1`, `|11-10|=1`, so all these elements can be there. But I can't add `4`, for example, because then the values would be >3: `|4-9|=5`, `|4-11|=7`, etc.

Comment: Just as a hint, it's like you're finding connected clusters in a graph. If x and y are in the same cluster, you no longer need to check y at all. You currently fully compute each cluster once for each of its members.

Comment: The answer looks correct for both, if I've understood the original statement and guessed the rest from the code. If it is not correct, you need to tell us what it should be.

Comment: Also dif needs to be a function parameter, and you didn't say how to handle duplicates.

Comment: Oh yeah, another hint - most of the time complexity savings will come from using sets for O(1) lookup with the "in" operator.